# Is the centroid of a contour always its geometrical centre? (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I am working with OpenCV+Python and I want to find the geometrical centre of the following contour:

[image]

The OpenCV documentation suggests the following to find the centroid of a contour:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('star.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv.threshold(img,127,255,0)
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
cnt = contours[0]
M = cv.moments(cnt)
print( M )

#Centroid
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
```

If I am right, according to this formula the centroid is calculated as the mean (or the average?) of all the points of the contour.
However, if for example fewer points are detected at the upper part of the contour than at the lower part of the contour then the centroid will be a bit higher than the actual geometrical centre of the (fully detected) contour.

Am I right?

If so, then is it better to calculate the average of the extreme points of the contour to find the geometrical centre of the contour and in this way to not depend at all on if the points of the contour are uniformly detected?

Comment: Official document is here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right?

No. The OpenCV function `moments()` uses [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) as mentioned in the [OpenCV `moments()` docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=cv2.moments#moments). Green's theorem is indeed a correct way to find the center of mass of a shape. Green's theorem specifically relates integrals about some shape to integrals about the shape's border. As such, it doesn't at all matter how many points define the border or not.

I say center of mass specifically, because you can pass in a single-channel image array into `moments()` as well to compute the moments and not just a point array. However for an image array, if the array is just binary, then the center of mass *is* the centroid. And with an array of points (from your contours), there is no array to tell the pixel values inside, so the result is similarly still the centroid.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not so sure that you are right. Firstly, Green theorem works for closed curves (even though w may close a curve and subtract the additional part from the whole outcome) so the number points does matter. Secondly, imagine in the image which I uploaded above that a small continuous part of the contour was missing then how Green theorem would now the exact area enclosed by this contour?

Comment: @Universalis those conditions don't exist. As you said, Green's theorem (and moments in general) exists only for closed curves and shapes. If you remove one of the sides, it is no longer a closed curve, so getting a moment doesn't make any sense. `moments()` always assumes a closed curve. And still no, the number of points does not matter. It's an integral. It doesn't matter whether your integral is in 10 pieces or 1, the answer is the same regardless.

Comment: Haha, ok, I got it. Even though my question was if the number of points does matter while you were responding about the number of pieces (of a presupposed closed curve).