# Centroid of a contour

Tags: python, opencv

In OpenCV under Python, is there no better way to compute the centroid of the inside a contour than with the function `cv2.moments`, which computes all moments up to order 3 (and is overkill) ?

Comment: You can try the mean like `np.mean(cnt, axis=0)`, but it depends how your contour is defined. Imagine a rectangle, in which the left side of the contour is defined with 20 points and the right side with only 10... the average will be skewed towards the left and won't be in the center, but the moments method does not care about this. If you have the whole area well define, then the average will be good enough. IMO is not overkill if you want to be precise always and with minimum amount of points defining your contour:)

Comment: Just to add more info about using mean or moments. Take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266277/is-the-centroid-of-a-contour-always-its-geometrical-centre-opencv-python)

Comment: @api55: I need the precise centroid of the inside, not of the outline.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use opencv? ( I believe you are already importing at least numpy)

Comment: @RickM.: no, I am open to (free) alternatives but the core must remain OpenCV (this decision is not under my control)

Comment: @YvesDaoust well, technically you can do that with numpy using the returned contours. Also, scipy.ndimage but I am not sure what your issue here is. Is it that `cv2.moments` is an overkill and you are looking for faster alternatives?

Comment: @RickM.: writing Python code would probably be too slow, I am after compiled functions. The function moments computes a lot too much. This is a real-time application.

Comment: @YvesDaoust may be [scipy's center of mass](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass.html)

Comment: @RickM.: is'nt that the average of the tuples, i.e. the centroid of the ouline ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well at the first look it would seem but you could use it for inside as well if you use correct labels. Also, why not make mask of the contour and calculate the mean to find the centroid if what you are looking for is inside and not the outline

Comment: @RickM.: the Green formula, as used by "moments", is much faster.

Comment: Might be worth trying to remove the second/third order component calculations in the C++ library, recompiling, and profile it against the normal function. This will at least give you an idea of how much of a speedup you could possibly gain from dropping those calculations.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds: quite right, stripping part of the code is doable. At first sight, this will make the function ten times faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats` it return the centroid and size of contour.

Comment: No, this computes for a blob, it's different when there are holes. And it's a very heavy function.